# javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Problem with PortableRemoteObject.toStub(); object not exported or stub not found

Tags: java, rmi, iiop

I am writing a Iiop server and I encountered the following error when I try to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Problem with PortableRemoteObject.toStub(); object not exported or stub not found [Root exception is java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: object not exported]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.corba.CorbaUtils.remoteToCorba(CorbaUtils.java:105)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.RemoteToCorba.getStateToBind(RemoteToCorba.java:79)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getStateToBind(NamingManager.java:870)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callBindOrRebind(CNCtx.java:600)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.rebind(CNCtx.java:713)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.rebind(CNCtx.java:730)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:433)
    at ExecRmiIiopServ.<init>(ExecRmiIiopServ.java:13)
    at ExecRmiIiopServ.main(ExecRmiIiopServ.java:20)
Caused by: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: object not exported
    at sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable.getStub(ObjectTable.java:124)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObject.toStub(RemoteObject.java:106)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.toStub(PortableRemoteObject.java:156)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.toStub(PortableRemoteObject.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.corba.CorbaUtils.remoteToCorba(CorbaUtils.java:99)
    ... 8 more
```

From what I've read about this error, I need a strongly typed declarations of an object so the Garbage Collector won't discard it, hence why I tried to add a functions object that does just that, but still the error persists, both in the normal run and with a breakpoint, the error triggering at the ctx.rebind line.

```
public class ExecRmiIiopServ {
    public ExecRmiIiopServ(String host, String port, String nume) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://" + host + ":" + port);
        ExecRmiInte functions = new ExecRmiImpl();
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        ctx.rebind(nume, functions);
        System.out.println("Java RMI IIOP waiting: " + host + ":" + port + "/" + nume);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if (args.length > 2)
            new ExecRmiIiopServ(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        else
            new ExecRmiIiopServ("localhost", "1050", "ExecIiop");
    }
}
```

The ExecRmiImpl() class is just this for now:

```
public class ExecRmiImpl implements ExecRmiInte {
    public ExecRmiImpl() { }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your remote object needs to either extend `PortableRemoteObject` or call its `exportObject()` method. At the moment it's just an object.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you.